# Como hacer para que un servidor cree varias paginas web flask

Tags: python, flask

Necesito crear un servidor que cree nuevas `url`. Todas las `url` tendrán que hacer lo mismo. Teniendo esta idea en mente creé el siguiente código:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from waitress import serve

def crear_paginas_web(elementos_a_crear):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    for contador in range(1, elementos_a_crear):
        nombre = '/configurar_elementos/elemento_' + str(contador)
        
        @app.route(nombre)
        def funcion():
            return 'hola'

    return app

    app = crear_paginas_web(elementos_a_crear=3)
     
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Pero este código devuelve el siguiente error:

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: funcion

Entiendo lo que quiere decir el error, pero si no puedo asignar la misma función a diferentes `url's` no se me ocurre como puedo hacerlo, ya que no se le puede asignar diferentes nombres a una función dentro de un bucle, y por más que haya investigado, no he encontrado como hacerlo.

¿Alguien sabe cómo poder solucionar el problema que tengo?

Comment: Por algo existen las urls dinámicas, investiga sobre eso

Comment: A lo que se refiere @Christian es a que para lograr lo que te propones, debes usar lo que se conoce como [Flask Router Params](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-tutorial-routes/). Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todas las URLs que intentas crear siguen un "patrón", en el que sólo cambia un número al final.

Flask permite crear rutas que encajen con patrones, y te deja especificar el nombre del parámetro en el que quieres capturar la parte que varía. Por ejemplo, en tu caso `"/configurar_elementos/elemento_<int:id>"` encajaría con las rutas que intentabas crear, siendo la parte que varía de tipo `int` y que guardaremos en el parámetro `id`.

Estas rutas "comodín" las asocias a una única función, pero esa función recibirá en su parámetro `id` el valor de la parte final de la ruta. Esto es precisamente lo que necesitas si todas las rutas al final van a hacer lo mismo. Y si quieres limitarlo a solo tres, en la función puedes verificar que `id` esté entre 1 y 3 (y de no ser así abortas con un error 404 por ejemplo).

Es decir, tu código queda tan simple como esto:

```
from flask import Flask, abort
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/configurar_elementos/elemento_<int:id>')
def funcion(id):
    if 1 <= id <= 3:
        return "hola"
    else:
        abort(404)

serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

### Comprobación de que funciona

Ejecutando curl desde línea de comandos con estas URLs vemos que se comporta como esperabas:

```
$ curl localhost:8000/configurar_elementos/elemento_1
hola

$ curl localhost:8000/configurar_elementos/elemento_2
hola

$ curl localhost:8000/configurar_elementos/elemento_3
hola

$ curl localhost:8000/configurar_elementos/elemento_4
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```